# How to specify a path where all files should go?

Tags: r

I am manipulating some files and would like to write the results and give them the same name as they had before manipulating.

Here is the code:

read the files:

```
  dir2 <- list.files("/data/reprojected", "*.img", full.names = TRUE) 
   results<- list()
```

compute:

```
 for (.files in seq_along(dir2)){
     file1 <- readBin(dir2[.files], numeric(), size = 4, n = 1440*720, signed = TRUE)
      results[[length(results) + 1L]]<- 500*file1
    for (i in seq_along(results)){
   fileName <- strsplit(dir2[i],split='\\.')[[1]][1]
   outputFile <- paste(fileName,'_rescaled','.img',sep='')
   writeBin(as.double(results[[i]]), outputFile, size = 4)}}
```

As you can see in this part of writing the files:

```
    for (i in seq_along(results)){
    fileName <- strsplit(dir2[i],split='\\.')[[1]][1]
    outputFile <- paste(fileName,'','.img',sep='')
   writeBin(as.double(results[[i]]), outputFile, size = 4)}
```

The files will be written and taken the same names as they had before and no problem with that.
 But they will be written in the same directory as they were before and previous files will be erased.
my question is how can we specify the path to a new directory in my cod(keeping the same names as before)?

Comment: Seems like a bit of unnecessarily looping. You should look at `lapply` for an easier interface for the for-loop and combine your loops into a single function.

Comment: Any idea on how we can use lapply instead?

Comment: Something like `lapply(dir2, function(x) { #a line to define outputFile then:\n writeBin(as.double(500*readBin(x, numeric(), size = 4, n = 1440*720, signed = TRUE), outputFile, size = 4) })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dirname` and `basename` split a pathname into the directory and file components, respectively. You can use this to substitute your own directory.

```
fileName <- strsplit(basename(dir2[i]), "\\.")[[1]][1]
fileName <- file.path(<new_directory>, fileName)
...
```

Comment: something like?:`fileName <- file.path(/donnees/rescaled, fileName)`